# Custom rule on an InfoPath control

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, infopath-rules

I am creating a SharePoint list form through InfoPath. The form is a request form where the visitors can key in their various requests.

I have one of the fields i.e. **Status** of the request.

Now what I want is that the control (i.e. textbox or any other control) corresponding to this field gets automatically updated to "Submitted" as soon as data is submitted. Then later the admin can change it to "work in progress" or "Processed Successfully" etc.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by setting up a rule on submit button once you have all validations successful before submit action update text filed with the value you want it to be.